# Output of Built-In Numpy Function to an Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The code I am writing (among other things) calculates the coefficients of the Legendre polynomial fit of my data.  I am writing it to do this in a piecewise fashion on my dataset, due to the presence of discontinuities in the data.  I'm having no problem getting the coefficients returned using

```
numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit()
```

but I need my output to be arrays.  When I try to have the coefficients output to an array using `array.append()` on an empty array, I'm getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Could someone advise me on how to get around this?  Thanks!

EDIT:  My problem stemmed from using square brackets where I should have used parentheses.  However, I couldn't see the forest for the trees, and it helped to get responses!

Comment: Can you show how you declared your array?

Comment: This kind of error usually indicates that you've made a typo (such as forgetting function call parentheses) or you've screwed up some basic concept (like mixing up data types or trying to call methods on the wrong thing). Whatever the case is, we'll need to see code to diagnose this. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best.

Comment: @paisanco, I can't.  The code I'm using it in is proprietary, as it is part of ongoing research.

Comment: @user2357112, thank you.  You pointed me towards the problem.  I used square brackets where I should have used parentheses.  Such a dumb mistake, but I've only been at this about a year.  Still in the "making dumb mistakes" phase!  Thank you!

Comment: Even with proprietary code though, you can post short examples that reproduce the error but don't necessarily contain the proprietary code.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, I'll remember that in the future.  However, it wound up not being necessary, as a simple explanation from user2357112 was sufficiently helpful.  I didn't necessarily need someone to sort out the code for me, but rather someone to translate what that error message meant.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
numpy.append(array, values)
```

in place of

```
array.append(values).
```